# Links Won't Open When Using Multiple Tabs (Jquery Tabs)

Tags: tabs

Code for multiple tabs on my page (displaying these tabs and content dynamically):

```
jQuery('.tab-block li a').click(function() {
var theitem = jQuery(this);
theitem.parent().parent().find("li").removeClass("active");
theitem.parent().addClass("active");
theitem.parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".tab-content > ul > li").removeClass("active");
theitem.parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".tab-content > ul > li").eq(theitem.parent().index()).addClass("active");
return false;
});
```

Code in my HTML to display tabs:

```
<div class="tab-block">
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
<li class="active"><a href="#">TAB 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TAB 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear-float"></div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
<ul>
<li class="active">
<p><h3><a href="http://www.google.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Goole.com</a></h3></a>
<p>Content</p>
</li>
<li>
<p><h3><a href="http://www.google.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Goole.com</a></h3></a>
<p>Content</p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Now all tabs work great but no links will open (the H3 link within the tabs themselves). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: No one can figure this out eh? Neither can I :(

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Change this line: .tab-block li a to .tabs li a and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your specific problem is, you may want to provide a link to a jsfiddle, to make yourself clear, but if you need tabs, try [EZ tabs](http://dcoder.eu/eztabs/) jQuery plugin.

HTML:

```
<div class="tab-block">
  <div class="tabs">
    <ul class='nav'>
      <li>TAB 1</li>
      <li>TAB 2</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear-float"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class='box'>
      <p>
      <h3><a href="http://www.google.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Goole.com</a></h3>
      </a>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class='box'>
      <p>
      <h3><a href="http://www.google.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Goole.com</a></h3>
      </a>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery, on document ready:

```
$('.tab-block').eztabs({
    tabsList : 'ul.nav',
    animation: 'slideLeftRight',
    boxContainer: '.tab-content',
    animationTime: 200
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wt4w1ud1/)